# What needs to be done in order to distribute a White-label app in the App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program, apple-developer, white-labelling

I made a custom White-label iOS app for a business. This business owner doesn't own any Apple products.

What steps need to be done in order to publish the iOS app under his business name?

I can share the iOS app IAP with him, but I don't know how to make the IPA (with a developer account, do I need to sign the IPA?).

Comment: To be published under his company name he will need to set up a developer program membership in the name of his company and then make you a member of the team so that you can publish the app

Comment: @Paulw11 : if he makes me a member of is team, does apple will not forbid the app saying the app is the same as my app (esspecially that both app are built from the same developer)?

Comment: Probably not. Apple is concerned about multiple identical apps published by one one person/company.

Comment: @Paulw11 : "probably" :( this what scared me ! I don't want to see my app being rejected because I personally upload on the app store several versions of this app in several accounts :(

Comment: There is no way to find out without submitting your app, however there are millions of apps on the store. It is impossible that a reviewer would be familiar with them all,  what they can see is other apps in the account they are currently working with. [Clause 4.2.6](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality) is what you need to worry about.

Comment: @Paulw11, thanks! but what you understand with this sentence in clause 4.2.6: These services should not submit apps on behalf of their clients and should offer tools that let their clients create customized, innovative apps that provide unique customer experiences. Me i understand that i can not submit myself the app ? or i m false ?

Comment: It means you can't submit apps under your developer program on behalf of clients. If your client has their own program membership then they are the one submitting the app (even if you are the one who actually presses the button if you know what I mean)

Comment: @Paulw11 I will try, we will see ... everything is complicated with apple :(

Comment: There are a lot of such applications in the appstore (based on white label). I don't think that Appstore will remove them (If they will be not identical at all of corse). The only thing I would like to notice - you will need to publish these apps on your or clients appstore account and do not publish your bare whitelabel ;) )

Answer (score 2):

My company makes white label apps. Each organization that signs up for our service has to create their own developer account and then invite me to be part of their account. Typically they invite me as an admin but that isn't completely necessary as long as I have enough privileges to create certs, upload builds, submit apps, etc.

My appleid is a member of a few dozen developer accounts and I use the same appleid to submit apps for each of those accounts. Apple has never rejected our apps because of that.

Comment: hi RudeDog, by the way do you have a tutorial you send to each organization explaining how to create a developer account and how to invite you to be part of their account ?

Comment: hey @rudebog my company has been publishing white label apps for clients but only today I got a rejection message for one of my apps while other got approved. do you know what could be the reason for that?

Comment: @rudedog I disapprove your answer because what you say it's false, i follow your advise and I get today my app rejected with the message "Design: Spam" :( so it's seam you was wrong :(

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I’ve never had an issue.