# Apple Developer Program: How to activate Two-factor authentication for Apple ID without access to an Apple device?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

A company want to distribute an iOS app I developed on their behalf. But in order to enrol into the Apple Developer Program, they are required to activate Two-factor authentication.

But they don't have a Mac, or an iOS device to receive an authentication code. How do I enable Two-factor authentication for their Apple ID?

Comment: Where’s the programming?

Comment: @matt : this is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61912223/what-someone-need-to-do-in-order-to-distribute-a-white-label-app-in-the-app-stor?noredirect=1#comment109505756_61912223

Comment: Well that’s off topic too. No one knows what Apple will do, and it’s not a programming matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a mobile number to receive verification code by SMS. Refer to this Apple Support document, [Two-factor authentication for Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204915)

> #### Trusted phone numbers
>
> A trusted phone number is a number that can be used to receive verification codes by text message or automated phone call. You must verify at least one trusted phone number to enroll in two-factor authentication.
>
> You should also consider verifying an additional phone number you can access, such as a home phone, or a number used by a family member or close friend. You can use this number if you temporarily can't access your primary number or your own devices.

---

#### Enabling and using two-step verification over SMS

To enable your mobile phone to receive two-step verification code, go to [Manage your Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/) website, login with the Apple ID, go to Security section, click edit and add a trusted phone number.

You'd be asked to verify it. Once you have it verified, you can use it to receive the two-step verification code as an SMS.

Comment: thanks yes, but question is how to activate this feature ?